# Android toolbar extra gap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-toolbar

I have seen the answer of this question but none of them work for me. In android  I have an extra gap between the margin and toolbar so it is not looking like a actionbar. How to remove that gap?[activity_main image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6do7.png)

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#FF7043"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"

android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"

android:id="@+id/tool_bar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#00E676"
tools:context="com.example.partha.customtitlebar.MainActivity">
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"


    ></include>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try it after removing android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" in the RelativeLayout or Change the layout into LinearLayout with the orientation="vertical"

Comment: That only solves the gap from the top

Comment: Can we able to see screenshot? which may help us to get more idea.

Comment: its because of the padding on the parent RelativeLayout... set the padding to 0dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the padding you have added to the parent RelativeLayout ViewGroup.

**you have two options**

- it's either you set the padding to 0dp but you will lose padding for the entire screen
- or you nest the the `TextView` inside another ViewGroup like `LinearLayout` and apply the padding to that `LinearLayout` rather than the `RelativeLayout`. with this you get the padding for your entire content while still making sure there is no padding around the `Toolbar` which will make it fit the screen like the deprecated ActionBar.

**This examples illustrate how you can achieve the second option**

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00E676"
tools:context="com.example.partha.customtitlebar.MainActivity">
<include
android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
layout="@layout/toolbar">
</include>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello World!"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, you'll notice that you've applied padding for all four sides on the `Toolbar`'s parent, i.e, the `RelativeLayout`

Removing the following lines will fix it:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```